# HTML rectangle box with angled corners

Tags: html, css

Trying to achieve a fluid rectangle with angled corners with html/css and sliced images.

Here is what i have so far.
http://jsfiddle.net/M888P/

```
<div class="main-title-wrapper">
<div class="main-title-inner">
<div class="main-title-top">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="main-title-left">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="main-title-right">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="strapline-container">
<h1 class="page-title">People for the hard places</h1>
<div class="sub-title-wrapper">
<p class="introtext">Together we can use our skills and passion to make a difference by going, giving and praying. Join our network of encouragers to see how you can help bring about God's great mission idea.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="main-title-bottom">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="main-title-tl">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="main-title-tr">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="main-title-bl">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="main-title-br">&nbsp;</div>

</div>
</div>
```

See image below[image: Image with rectangle angles]

Comment: Frankly, use an image...sometimes it's the best option. At best use the `border-image` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much cleaner way would be to use [`border-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) to align and size the image around content. You will only have to download a single image instead of one for every facet, and the code is much more readable.

At border-image.com, you can [generate the proper css](http://border-image.com/#%7B%22src%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FziNitLf.png%22%2C%22linkBorder%22%3Atrue%2C%22borderWidth%22%3A%5B0%2C0%2C0%2C0%5D%2C%22imageOffset%22%3A%5B39%2C43%2C41%2C46%5D%2C%22fill%22%3Atrue%2C%22setRepat%22%3Afalse%2C%22repeat%22%3A%5B%22repeat%22%2C%22repeat%22%5D%2C%22scaleFactor%22%3A0.5599647266313933%2C%22setRepeat%22%3Atrue%7D):

```css
.banner {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 39px 43px 41px 46px;
    -webkit-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/ziNitLf.png) 39 43 41 46 repeat;
       -moz-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/ziNitLf.png) 39 43 41 46 repeat;
         -o-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/ziNitLf.png) 39 43 41 46 repeat;
            border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/ziNitLf.png) 39 43 41 46 fill repeat;
}
```

#### [Working Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/2YL4D/)

Comment: Thanks Kyle, need to support ie8 also but i think thats where csspie comes in handy. Cheers again.